# Cual es la forma correcta de crear test en angular?

Tags: angular

estoy iniciando en el testing, y comencé a seguir tutoriales en la web , pero al hacer la primera prueba me lanza el siguiente error.

Me seria de gran ayuda sus respuestas y como abordar las pruebas unitarias.

Aca les comparto lo que creo que puede ser útil para mi pregunta

este es el codigo del componente

```
export class PreciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasComponent implements OnInit {
headersExcel: any[];
constructor(private logger: Logger, private dialogsService: DialogsService, public behaviorTableService: BehaviorTableService, private helpersService: HelpersService, private printService: PrintService, private spinnerService: SpinnerService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private excelService: ExcelService, private preciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasService: PreciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.spinnerService.restart();
    this.spinnerService.estadoCarga.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
        this.cargandoSpinner = val;
    });

    //this.idiomaCalendario = this.helpersService.localESPrimeCalendarConfig();

    this.resolucionDatosCargados = this.route.snapshot.data['initData'].objParams;

    this.periodo = this.resolucionDatosCargados['dates'];

    this.infoPorSemanaTemporada = this.resolucionDatosCargados['perWeek'];

    this.listadoSemanas = this.resolucionDatosCargados['listSemanas'];
    this.parametros['semana'] = this.listadoSemanas[0][0];

    this.listadoMercados = this.resolucionDatosCargados['listMarkets'];
    this.parametros['mercado'] = this.listadoMercados[0]['empCod']; // Seleccionar primer item del listado.

    // const distinc = (value, index, self)=>{
    //     return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    //   }
    this.displayInfoPeriodAvailable();
    // this.listadoAnniosTemporadas = this.listadoSemanas.filter(distinc);
    this.listadoAnniosTemporadas = [...new Map(this.listadoSemanas.map(item => [item[1], item])).values()];

    // Obtene listado, selecciona la primera opción
    this.listadoSemanaTemporada = this.listadoSemanas.filter(list=> list[1] === this.listadoAnniosTemporadas[0][1]);
    this.annioSeleccionado = this.listadoAnniosTemporadas[0][1];
    this.parametros['annio'] = this.listadoSemanaTemporada[1][1];

    // Obtene listado y selecciona la primera opción
    this.parametros['semana'] =  this.listadoSemanas[0][0];
}
```

Este es el archivo de spect.ts este es el formato por defecto que me entrega angular al crear el componente, estuve tratando de hacer condiciones mas simples pero sigo teniendo casi los mismos errores

````
import { PreciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasComponent } from './precios-flores-ultimas-diez-semanas.component';

describe('PreciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasComponent', () => {
  let component: PreciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PreciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ PreciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasComponent ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PreciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  })
  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  })
  
})```

Este es el codigo de error que me entrega al ejecutar ng test.

    NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Logger -> Logger]: 
          NullInjectorError: No provider for Logger!
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'Logger', 'Logger' ] })
        NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[Logger -> Logger]: 
          NullInjectorError: No provider for Logger!
            at NullInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11081:27)
            at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11247:33)
            at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:11247:33)
            at NgModuleRef$1.get (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25341:33)
            at Object.get (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:25055:35)
            at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3342:39)
            at getOrCreateInjectable (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3454:12)
            at ɵɵdirectiveInject (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:14714:12)
            at NodeInjectorFactory.factory (ng:///PreciosFloresUltimasDiezSemanasComponent/ɵfac.js:4:68)
            at getNodeInjectable (node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:3549:44)
        Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
````

Comment: Recuerda que el código y los errores se comparten como texto. No sabemos cómo es el init de tu componente, pero seguramente usas un servicio para instanciar un Logger  y al correr las unitarias, ese recurso no existe porque no levantas toooooooda la app, sólo este componente (son unitarias). Tienes que hacer mock del servicio e importar ese mock en el ts de pruebas donde estás definiendo este escenario (.spec.ts)

Comment: Te recomiendo completar el [tour] (así además te ganas una medalla más) y leer [ask]. Es mucho mejor poner tanto el código que falla como el error como texto (si no sabes como formatearlo, siempre podemos echar una mano, editándolo posteriormente). Una imagen no permite copiar el código a la respuesta y además no puedes leerla sin zoom (se ve todo borroso y pequeño)